# How to retrieve the GameplayEvent payload from a GameplayAbility trigger?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-gameplay-ability-system

When using Unreals [GameplayAbilitySystem](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Gameplay/GameplayAbilitySystem), a *GameplayAbility* can be triggered using a *GameplayEvent*.

When using `UAbilityTask_WaitGameplayEvent`, the *GameplayEvent* provides a payload of class `FGameplayEventData`.

[image: WaitGameplayEvent]

Is it possible to retrieve such an event payload also from within a  *GameplayAbility*, after it is activated by a trigger of type *GameplayEvent*?

[image: A GameplayAbility GameplayEvent trigger]

A solution either in Blueprint or C++ would be fine.

Comment: I think this question should be asked on the Game Development website!

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time but I think I should add an answer in case someone else comes here. After doing what you did in your pictures, you can go to your ability and delete the default 'Event ActivateAbility' and instead over-ride 'Event ActivateAbilityWithEvent'. Important to delete the default, you *have* to do it otherwise it will default to using it and won't trigger.

Once done, sending your trigger tag will start the ability and call this new event which will have your payload and anything else you want to send. Hope that helps!